# Create new custom page for PrestaShop 1.5

Tags: prestashop, prestashop-1.5

I have a big problem, please I really need some help. I am trying to add a new custom page for my Prestashop and I can't. I don't want to add it thru admin panel, I did next thing:NewPageController.php (controller->front..), newpage.php in root folder +newpage.tpl in theme directory(not default theme, my theme). I get something like http://mydomain.com/en/index.php?controller=newpage , and my page is completly empty.
There is NewPageController.php:

Thanks everybody a lot. I am waiting answear.Thank you!

Comment: Please enable errors at prestashop admin, and post the error message. Also place error_reporting(E_ALL); at your controller init function.

Comment: pls have a look @ http://blog.gofenice.com/prestashop/creating-custom-front-page-in-prestashop/

Answer (score 0):

Make a new module containing your controller (extending ModuleFrontController) pointing to your view .tpl . The new page will be accessible on the URL [base url]/?fc=module&module=[your module name]&controller=[your controller name].
Advantage of this is that your view will automatically include the site's theme layout and all you will have to implement is the rest of the content while sametime you will have available all core functions, variables and context of the controller.

[Official Prestashop 1.5 documentation](http://doc.prestashop.com/display/PS15/New+Developers+Features+In+PrestaShop+1.5)

Comment: Module for new page!?! something odd, it wil give name of modulde in link